# What are the convenient and secured alternatives to github / gitlab ssh keys

Tags: git, github, gitlab

My corporate network restricts communications on port 22, so I can't connect to GitHub/GitLab using the SSH key authentication.

What are the secure (and, if possible, convenient) alternatives ?

Comment: I _think_ you can use ssh against port 443 in github (because _they_ support it, not because it's a standard feature of https).

Comment: See https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port and https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/#alternative-ssh-port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for GitHub, you can use SSH over port 443 by using `ssh.github.com`, which may be an easy way to use SSH keys if you like.

If you can't use SSH, then typically the other choice is HTTPS.  Both GitHub and GitLab offer personal access tokens, which are randomly generated tokens that can be used to authenticate.

The secure way to store personal access tokens is in a credential helper (configured with `credential.helper`), which varies across platforms.  On Windows, either `manager` or `wincred` is used; on macOS, `osxkeychain` is available by default; and on Linux, `libsecret` is the preferred option (although on some systems you may need to compile it yourself).  If you must, you can also use the `store` credential helper, which is always available, although it's less preferred because it doesn't store the token encrypted.

You should not put the credential in the URL, because it is definitely stored unencrypted there and it's very common for URLs to be printed to the screen or exposed in `ps` output or for repositories to leak, in which case the credentials would be exposed.  Git will likely remove this functionality in the future.